# What is the relation between the perfect squares and prime numbers?

Tags: probability, number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers

$\hspace{10pt}$I was playing with R and a list of the first 10,000 primes and suddenly I had the idea of looking how many perfect squares are between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$.

$\hspace{10pt}$I make a program in R to compute it and I get an impressive result; we always have one or none.
Also, I compute the number of times that we have a perfect square over the total gaps and my result was approximately $\frac{1}{3}$. In other words the probability that a perfect square is in $(p_{n},p_{n+1})$ is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Anyone here know some results related to this?

Comment: This is related to the famous Legendre conjecture which states that there exists a prime $p$ between two consecutive squares, $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.

Comment: sum over inverse of all perfect squares converges but not for inverse of primes.

Comment: There is a stronger conjecture https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppermann%27s_conjecture

Comment: @Rohan I knew about this conjecture, but what about the probability of a certain random interval with consecutive prime intervals that contains a perfect square ? The probability seems to be 1/3 and binomial distribution.

Comment: Removing the **[perfect-numbers]** tag, as this question has got nothing to do with the divisor sum function $\sigma=\sigma_1$.